# Set subsequent row values based on input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to set the value of all cells after a certain date with a defined value? For example, if I input Jul-19 into cell A4, can I fill all cells in a separate row directly below and after this date with the value 28,000, and those before with 0? See below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in A2 and copy/drag over:

```
=IF(A1>=$A$4,28000,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `If()` formula:

```
=IF(A1<$A$4,0,28000)
```

Edit: ...in complete opposition to @ScottCraner's answer :P

Comment: One less character for the win :P

Answer (score 3):

```
=(A1>=$A$4)*28000
```

Something a little shorter and no IF

Edit: and inline with the craner method!

Comment: Oooh, clever! :D

Comment: @brucewayne I believe it only works for situations where 0 or some number are the final results since you are multiplying by 1 or 0.  Some number could be generated by another formula.  Will not work in a situation where you need "" or some text.

Comment: One less character... replace `28000` with `28E3`. haha